100 people (30 men and 70 women) are divided evenly into 5 groups. What is the probability that at least one group has more men than women?
Given a population of 100 with 30 men and 70 women. They are divided into 5 groups each of size 20. What is the probability that at least one group has more men than women?

Hint: What is the complement of "at least one group has more men than women"?

Another idea: You are interested in non negative solutions to:
$$w_1+w_2+…+w_5=70$$
$$m_1+m_2+…+m_5=30$$
$$m_j+w_j=20$$

Please show the own effort to solve the problem, it is the way it works on this site. Also state a specific question. Short posts of the shape "Here is my problem, solve it for me!" are not warmly received, they are in great danger to collect quick close votes (we have three of them now), and to be closed for the reason of missing details. So please edit the question to provide more context. See also https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question, where on the first place providing context is mentioned.

See the comment that I left, following the answer of Kadmos.

You are interested in non negative solutions to:
$$w_1+w_2+…+w_5=70$$
$$m_1+m_2+…+m_5=30$$
$$m_j+w_j=20$$
An analyst would say (and a computer could probably solve this):
$$p=1-\frac{\sum_{w_1+…+w_5=70 ; 10\leq w_i\leq 20}1}{\sum_{w_1+…+w_5=70 ; 0\leq w_i\leq 20}1}$$
I am really curious about the proper combinatorial point of view.
EDIT: $p=1- 7051/41371\approx 0.8296$ after a quick MATLAB code.
sol=0
solWoman=0

for w1=1:20
    for w2=1:20
        for w3=1:20
            for w4=1:20
                for w5=1:20
                if w1+w2+w3+w4+w5==70 
                    sol=sol+1;
                    if 9<w1 & 9<w2 & 9<w3 & 9<w4 & 9<w5
                        solWoman=solWoman+1;
                    end
                end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end

p=1-solWoman/sol

EDIT 2 After seeing the comment sections: of course the equiprobable events are ambiguous. I could assign groups of people with equal probability (which appears to be the standard approach) or I could fix the number of elements of women and men in each group and assign these with equal probability (which yields my first approach). In the former case, we have:
$$
p = 1 - \frac{N}{\binom{100}{20, 20, 20, 20, 20}}
$$
Where $
N=\sum_{w_1+…+w_5=70 ; 10 \leq w_i \leq 20} $ $\binom{70}{w_1, w_2, w_3, w_4, w_5}$ $ \binom{30}{20-w_1,20-w_2,…20-w_5}
$ is the number of ways of choosing people to be in groups such that there is always less or equal number of men in each group. This is not easier to calculate then the first approach and is probably more computationally demanding because of factorials. If the probability density is not precisely assigned in the question, I would say the question is ill posed…
Final note: The OP has contributed in the comment section below, so I think we should give him a warmer welcome in our community.

Stars and Bars theory generally doesn't play well in probability problems.  That is, in general the $~\displaystyle \binom{n +[k-1]}{k-1}~$ solutions to  $~x_1 + \cdots + x_k = n,~$ are not equally likely.  Instead, I suggest that you consider that the number of (equally likely) different ways that you can have $~m~$ men and $~w~$ women in one specific group is $~\displaystyle \binom{30}{m} \times \displaystyle \binom{70}{w}.~$ Here, over-simplifying by focusing only on 1 specific group, you need $~m+w = 20,~$ and $~m \geq 11.$

Is this more reasonable?
$$\frac{\sum_{10\leq w_j \leq 20}{70\choose w_1}{30\choose 20-w_1} {70-w_1 \choose w_2}{30-(20-w_1)\choose 20-w_2}… {70-w_1-w_2-w_3\choose w_4}{30-(20-w_1)-(20-w_2)-(20-w_3)\choose 20-w_4}}{{100 \choose 20} {80 \choose 20 } {60 \choose 20} {40 \choose 20}}$$

The $~\sum_{10 \leq w_j \leq 20}~$ approach won't wash, because you haven't explicitly defined $~w_j.~$ Let $~S~$ denote the complete set of all possible ordered 5-tuples $~(w_1, w_2, w_3, w_4, w_5),~$ where each $~w_i~$ is an element in $~{0,1,2,\cdots,10},~$ and $~w_1 + w_2 + \cdots + w_5 = 30.~$  Then, you want $$N = \sum_{(w_1,w_2,\cdots,w_5) \in S} \left[ ~\prod_{k=1}^5 \binom{30}{w_k} \times \binom{70}{20 - w_k} ~\right].$$ Then, the probability will be given by $$1 - \frac{N}{\binom{100}{20}\binom{80}{20}\binom{60}{20}\binom{40}{20}}.$$

While computing $N$,  we should have $30-w_k$. Similary we should subtract out the number of women already selected in the earlier committees.

@NibeshShrestha Very nice catch, my mistake.  Correcting my previous comment, it should be $$N = \sum_{(w_1,w_2,\cdots,w_5) \in S} f(w_1,w_2,\cdots,w_5),$$ where $$f(w_1,w_2,\cdots,w_5) = \binom{30}{w_1}\binom{70}{20 - w_1}\binom{30-w_1}{w_2}\binom{50+w_1}{20 - w_2}\binom{30-w_1-w_2}{w_3}\binom{30+w_1+w_2}{20 - w_3}\binom{30-w_1-w_2-w_3}{w_4}\binom{10+w_1+w_2+w_3}{20 - w_4}.$$
